# Load jquery conditionally with pure JavaScript if windows with < than 600px

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to load jquery conditionally with pure JavaScript if windows with < than 600px and to put an "else" that load jquery in a async way?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
var sync;
if (window.outerWidth < 600) {
  sync = false;
} else {
  sync = true;
}

function loadScript(sync) {
  var script = document.createElement("script");
  script.type = "text/javascript";
  script.async = sync;
  script.src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.1/jquery.js";
  document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
};
loadScript(sync);
```

Comment: Thanks yezzz. I've tried but it seems that the jquery does not load.

Comment: I think it does. Maybe you're using jquery functions before jquery gets loaded. Example with jquery: https://jsfiddle.net/6epe4w7p/